Old movie where they hide a train in a secret tunnel covered by a secret door
There is a chase going on with steam engine trains. The leading train suddenly stops at a switch, and backs off on a side track which ends in a tunnel. They close the tunnel entrance with a secret door covered by fake rocks. And somehow cover also the last few meters of the railway that leads to the tunnel door by fake sand. The movie is set in a more desert like location with some hills. (As far as I remember there is also a railway gun in the movie, but I may be wrong about that).
I think it took place somewhere between 1900 and 1950 in a desert like area with some small hill. As far as I remember there was also a handcar/draisine. The trains had a steam engine. The good guys (a group of men, maybe one woman) were on a train that was followed by another train by bad guys (maybe an army of WW1 / WW2). The good guys hid their train in a tunnel. Maybe there was also a self playing piano scene, or it was another movie I saw on that very same day, many years ago.

Do you remember any background details at all? Year, country, general plot, characters\actors etc.?

I think it played somewhen between 1900 and 1950. It played in a desert like area with some small hill. As far as I remember there was also a handcar/draisine. The trains had steam engine. The good guys (a group of men, maybe one woman) were on a train that was followed by another train by bad guys (maybe an army of WW1 / WW2). The good guys hid their train in a tunnel. (maybe there was also a self playing piano scene, or it was another movie I saw on that very same day, many years ago)

Thanks (and added), but by year I meant the year (or even decade) of release.

It's been a long time since I've seen it, but there is a Disney Movie called The Great Locomotive Chase (1956) that has a lot of scenes like this. In it a group of Union soldiers sneak into Confederate territory  to steal a train during the American Civil War. The Confederates give chase in their own train, and the Yankees use all sorts of trickery to keep them off their trail. There was a lot of track switching, dropping train cars, and leaving obstacles along the track. I don't remember that specific scene, but look it up and see if that's the one you're thinking of.

